# Why am I getting 'int object not iterable' error?

Tags: python, mysql, types

Here is my bit of code that's causing the error. I have searched this issue online but I can't find a source that helps me remedy the problem in my code. I am using python to execute SQL commands but the issue here is with the python. I don't see why the code is trying to iterate through the variable 'x.'

```
while True:
    x = 1
    #states = api.get_states()
    for s in states.states:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE aircraft SET latitude = %s, longitude = %s, velocity = %s, heading = %s, callsign = %s", ( getLat(s), getLon(s), getVel(s), getHeading(s), getCallsign(s)))
        cursor.execute("WHERE entry = %r;",x)  #this line is causing the error
        x += 1
    y = input("Database updated, enter 1 to update again or enter 0 to exit ")
    if (y == 1):
        continue
    elif (y == 0):
        print("Exiting program...")
        break
```

Comment: @Spiderman thanks for your reply, why would that cause the error?

Comment: I am printing it out every loop iteration and it prints out a state vector which I expect, so I suppose the last iteration of the for loop is what is causing the problem.

Comment: It would be helpful to any seeking to answer if you specified the package you're using to communicate with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using a MySQL DBAPI 2.0 compliant package, there are two problems with the code here.

The first is that DBAPI 2.0 specifies that query parameters are to be provided as an iterable or a mapping. Putting the value x in tuple or a list would solve that issue.

```
    cursor.execute("UPDATE aircraft SET latitude = %s, longitude = %s, velocity = %s, heading = %s, callsign = %s", ( getLat(s), getLon(s), getVel(s), getHeading(s), getCallsign(s)))
    cursor.execute("WHERE entry = %r;", tuple(x)) # [x] would also be valid.
```

Also, the whole statement needs to be part of one call to `cursor.execute`. `WHERE entry = 1` is not a complete SQL statement.

Source:
[PEP 249 - DBAPI 2.0 Specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15)

**Edit:** Showing how I would write the query in a single execute call.

```
    cursor.execute("""
        UPDATE aircraft
        SET latitude = %s, longitude = %s, velocity = %s, heading = %s, callsign = %s
        WHERE entry = %r
      """,
      (getLat(s), getLon(s), getVel(s), getHeading(s), getCallsign(s), x)
    )
```

The multiline string achieves the effect I think op was going for with the staement splitting, and SQL generally doesn't care about extra whitespace.

Comment: What would be the correct way to make it one cursor.execute call?

Comment: So I added your edit to my code, I dont get any errors but it causes my program to sit and stall at the cursor.execute statement.

Comment: That probably doesn't have anything to do with my approach. It seems like you might resolve it by committing to the DB after the update or closing the cursor. Perhaps look for known issues similar to this related to your DBAPI module.